# How to trigger an on change event with some predefined value

Tags: jquery

I have the follwing jsfiddle , which actually displays all the values (status values pending , declined  approved) initially .

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/29/

My requiremnt is that initially i want to display only the values taht are having status as pending .

I tried putting this call

```
//$('#filterstatus').val('pending').trigger('change');
```

But this is not working .

Could anybody please let me know how to display only the pending values ??

Comment: use if() else () statement to check if it is filled with pending

Comment: Your trigger() line is before the on() line. Also your HTML isn't valid, as the delete button is inside the <select>.

Comment: Did it work? Leave a response if it works thats also helpfull for other people who find things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is the best idea if I think what you think.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $("#filterstatus").val();
    if (data == 'pending') {
        //run code
    }
});
</script>
```